# No more documentation about signature & EIP 1271

Tags: gnosis-safe

Hello I was looking for the part of documentation for signature handled by Safe wallet. Any reason it has been removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the documentation for that here: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/main/docs/signatures.md

Safe is currently working on restructuring the docs and that document wasn't at the relevant location, so it was removed.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @GianluK.eth make sure to mark this as an answer, helps the community.